# Display visualforce page in console

Tags: visualforce, console

So all I am trying to do is create a very basic visualforce page to display in a console.  At the minute all that exists on the page is:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" >
hello there  
</apex:page>
```

I've added the page as a tab in the console but it stays blank...I've been looking at the salesforce integration toolkit but none of the basic samples display.  There are no links, so I haven't whitelisted any domains etc.

Apologies to ask this, it is no doubt something really obvious.

Comment: What's the URL you use to access the page?

Comment: I've added it as a visualforce tab....?  It's really just to display information - the page doesn't need to "do" anything just now.

Comment: Also, worth adding that if I display the tab in an app that isn't a console it displays as expected.

Comment: Under your org's Session Settings, do you have "Enable clickjack protection for customer Visualforce pages with headers disabled" turned on?

Comment: Yeah, I've just turned them off and that fixed it!!!  Could you set the answer and i'll tick it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have 'Enable clickjack protection for customer Visualforce pages with headers disabled' it will block VF pages in the console. This is because each tab in the console is an iFrame, and VF pages are served from a separate domain than the main console. So this security setting will block VF pages from being served in the console.

The workaround is to disable this setting.

See [this doc](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_vf_clickjack_with_headers_disabled.htm) where it's mentioned briefly that this setting can cause problems in the console.